# Error using the Facebook Open Graph API when logging in

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do you use the open graph API to display a facebook login button, and get the username and email after a successful login?  I've tried this but with no success.

I have this in the head section:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: '12345', cookie: true,
        status: true, xfbml: true
    });          

    FB.api('/me', function (user) {
        if (user != null) {
            alert(user.name);
        }
    });
</script>
```

I placed `<div id="fb-root"></div>` at the very end just before the `</body>` tag. So far so good. My `<fb:comments> and <fb:comments-count>` work fine from any page on my site. But I am unable to get my login to work (it says I don't have fb-root defined)

I have this somewhere in the middle of my page:

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_checkins">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

After submitting on the login window, I get a js error that says fb-root div not defined. But I do have it at the end of the page.

Comment: If you can, use the php scheme.. Much better...

Comment: Probably unrelated, but don't use /me without making sure you are logged in before. See my answer for a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Asynchronous Loading](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.init/)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '12345',
      cookie: true,
      status: true,
      xfbml: true
    });

    FB.api('/me', function(user) {
      if (user != null) {
        alert(user.name);
      }
    });

  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: Also, you should put the `#fb-root` div _before_ the script tag.  This ensures that it is defined before the script executes.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the initialization inside a function that you call at the very end, i.e. :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function fbInit() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '12345', cookie: true,
                    status: true, xfbml: true
                });          
            }       
            if(FB.getSession() != null) {
                // user logged in, continue with the program.  
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            fbInit();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or, even better, inside a `$(document).ready()` (using jQuery)